# Wordpress metadata taxonomy filter no result

Tags: wordpress

My question is about the metadata taxonomy filter plugin in Wordpress.

I installed the plugin and do the settings but when I want to filter it doesn't work. In fact, it doesn't show any results at all.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: you should better contact with plugin author?

Comment: Does some of you have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using a plugin for Wordpress taxonomy filter to work, will not be efficient. If you make your filter by yourself, then you have more access and control over it.

Check this out. This is an example of Wordpress multiple taxonomy filter with AJAX. https://convertintowordpress.com/wordpress-multiple-taxonomy-filter-ajax/